# Embed LinkedIn post into Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, embed, linkedin-api

#linkedin I'd like to embed this post
"https://www.linkedin.com/posts/manish-khatta_airline-earnings-are-starting-to-trickle-activity-6692063523570376704-DpK3/";
into a blog article, we are creating to profile Manish (the author of this post). I can do this easily via Twitter, but cannot figure out how to embed the post into our WordPress blog platform. Please let me know if there's a solution to this challenge. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you looking for a way to program this functionality, or are you looking for a plugin or other way to do this? Please note that this is a site for specific programming-related questions. If your question is programming related, then please edit it to include the specific question you have. Questions about WP administration etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com). If you are looking for a plugin, that is also off topic for this site.

Comment: Apologies if my question is off topic for this site. I was directed here from LinkedIn after inquiring with my question.

Comment: They're sending people to a site manned by volunteers for help? The cheek! :) If your question is programming-related, then it isn't off topic but we do need more information. Otherwise you could try the WP Stack Exchange (check their help first to see what's on topic there) or try searching for a plugin to do this, I'm sure there must be some out there.

Comment: I'd consider it to be programming-related as it requires some code manipulation on the back-end of Wordpress to make it work on Twitter. LinkedIn provides an embed code "<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6692063523020926976" height="721" width="504" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" title="Embedded post"></iframe>" but when I enter that code, Wordpress is not fetching that code to embed the content into our blog.

Comment: If you consider it to be a programming related, then you should edit your question to show the related information so that it is on topic. Include the info from your comment and also the details of what you have tried & where you added this code. Including it in the comments is not enough as other people who could help might not see it.